# Java program freezes without error

Tags: java

I am making a game, and my java program freezes without error.
I made a Trail for my object, so it looks cool. Without the Trail it works like a charm, but when I add the Trail to the object it works for like 2-3 seconds and it freezes.

```
package myfirstgame;

import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;



public class Trail extends GameObject{

    private float alpha = 1;
    private Handler handler;
    private Color color;
    private int width, height;
    private float life;

    public Trail(int x, int y, ID id, Color color, int width, int height, float life,Handler handler) {
        super(x, y, id);
        this.handler = handler;
        this.color = color;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.life = life;
    }


    public void tick() {
        if(alpha > life){
            alpha -= (life - 0.0001f);
        }else {
            handler.removeObject(this);
        }
    }


    public void render(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setComposite(makeTransparent(alpha));
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);

        g2d.setComposite(makeTransparent(1));

    }

    private AlphaComposite makeTransparent(float alpha){
        int type = AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER;

        return(AlphaComposite.getInstance(type, alpha));
    }


    public Rectangle getBounds() {

        return null;
    }

}
```

Then in my Game.java i have this:

```
handler.addObject(new BasicEnemy(r.nextInt(WIDTH), r.nextInt(HEIGHT),ID.BasicEnemy, handler));
```

And in my BasicEnemy.java:

```
handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y, ID.Trail, Color.red, 16,16, 0.01f, handler));
```

Comment: Can you observe the stack when frozen or just before with one of the JDK tools (thinking about jvisualvm ) ? Maybe it will give you some hints.

Comment: I tried but jvisualvm is freezing too.

Comment: Maybe the `Trail`should not try to remove itself from the handler. You add the Trail with `handler.addObject(new Trail(x, y, ID.Trail, Color.red, 16,16, 0.01f, handler));` and inside the Trail you call `handler.removeObject(this);`

Comment: However without the remove, the FPS are going from very high to 0?!?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that **AWT components freeze** when used transparently, and are only able to update when not **visible**.

---